# Загрузка графа объектов

Tags: java, хранение-данных, dao

**Задача:** Есть класс А и класс В:

```
public final class A {
    private final int ID;
    private final String VALUE;
    private final B OBJECT_B;

    //... конструктор и методы
}

public class B {
    private int id;
    private String value;

    //... конструктор и методы
}
```

Необходимо определить архитектурный подход для загрузки объектов обоих типов из реляционной СУБД *без использования ORM*, с учетом следующего:

1. Между сущностями типов А и В установлено отношение один-ко-многим (на объект/запись типа/таблицы В может ссылаться на несколько объектов/записей типа/таблицы А).
2. Необходимо избегать проблемы N + 1 (обращение к СУБД производится удалено и объектов много)
3. Объекты типа А неизменяемы и как следствие - поле OBJECT_B должно быть проинициализированно в момент конструирования.
4. Объекты класса А и В могут загружаться и обрабатываться по отдельности (поле OBJECT_B у объектов типа А может иметь значение null). Поэтому для них имеются отдельные таблицы связанные через foreighn key.
5. Загрузка и сохранение объектов осуществляется с использованием паттерна DAO.
6. Граф объектов ацикличен, глубина не больше двух, объекты одного и того же типа не ссылаются друг на друга.

**Как я пытался решить задачу:**
На данный момент нашел простое решение "в лоб". Есть некий менеджер всех объектов. Он хранит закешированные объекты после выборок в ассоциативных массивах. Он же и отвечает за обращение к СУБД через DAO. DAO интерфейс для класса А будет выглядеть примерно во так

```
public interface ADao {
    public void add(A a) throws Exception;
    public void delete(A a) throws Exception;
    public void update(A a) throws Exception;
    public A getA(int id, Map<Integer,B> bObjects) throws Exception;
    public List<A> getAll(Map<Integer,B> bObjects) throws Exception;
```

}

**Вопрос:** существуют ли какие-нибудь best-practis для решения подобных задач?

Comment: а где граф? как они связаны?

Comment: боюсь "в лоб" будет "N + 1" на getA. а если future возвращать?

Comment: Скажите пожалуйста, почему вы думаете, что возникнет проблема "N + 1"? Если в переданном Map не окажется нужного объекта B, то разумеется он будет получен отдельным запросом в СУБД. Но если я правильно понимаю, проблема "N + 1" имела бы место только в том случае, если бы мы за раз получали много объектов А через один запрос, а потом для каждого из них отдельным запросом подгружали свой объект В.

Comment: Не до конца понятно из вопроса, как A и B образуют граф. Если граф глубокий, то `Map<...,B>` всё не вытянет, и связи от B дальше снова надо будет запрашивать для каждого B. А запрашивать на всю глубину сразу может быть затратно по объему. В конкретном случае "в лоб" может хватить. Но если глубина не определена, и проход по условию, то можно всё построить на возврате и комбинации футур. Задания можно собирать и отправлять оптом. Насколько это красиво запишется на java и для графа -- не скажу. В scala -- я нормально использовал футуры для распараллеливания вычислений. В котлине есть сопрограммы.

Comment: есть еще neo4j -- графовая DB

Comment: "Не до конца понятно из вопроса, как A и B образуют граф." - спасибо за дельное замечание. Глубина графа не больше двух узлов, граф ацикличен. Добавил это уточнение в описание задачи.

Comment: "есть еще neo4j -- графовая DB" - интересное предложние, но хотелось бы найти решение не зависящее от типа СУБД.